# Process of the ARIMA Model

Tags: forecasting

I am trying to do the ARIMA Model in XLMINER. I have followed these steps.

---

1. Data Partition the time-series. Question- Do we even need to partition the time series for the ARIMA Model. Link [here](https://www.otexts.org/fpp/8/7) does not tell that you need to partition the data.

---

2. If you partition (training,validation) the time-series and you get a different ACF and PACF Plots for training and validation how do you decide which (p,d,q) will fit the model best.

Here is the time-series data: 130 162 196 481 162 166 296 169 376 267 206 272 271 197 140 290 252 204 117 334 228 287 252 256 261 247 206 206 231 239 179 169 108 285 142 74 225 200 84 144 233 138 200 130 148 125 171 117 186 131 157 56 It is weekly data and there is no seasonality and I have data only for 1 year (2005)

Thanks,
Rajesh

Comment: Welcome to SO. Do you have a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) you could post?

Comment: Here is the time-series data: 130
162
196
481
162
166
296
169
376
267
206
272
271
197
140
290
252
204
117
334
228
287
252
256
261
247
206
206
231
239
179
169
108
285
142
74
225
200
84
144
233
138
200
130
148
125
171
117
186
131
157
56
It is weekly data and there is no seasonality and I have data only for 1 year (2005)

Comment: Please edit your MCVE into your question.